# ¿Por que me sale Android.OS.FileUriExposedException en una clase y en otra funciona bien en Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, pdf, excepciones, xamarin.android, uri

Tengo un proyecto de **Xamarin.Android** en el que armo un PDF y luego debo mostrarlo.
Para no tener que hacer todo el circuito completo, hice una clase `Test.cs` la cual uso de MainLauncher para hacer todo el diseño del PDF. En esta clase todo funciona perfecto y sin problemas, puedo generar el PDF y luego abrirlo.

Cuando terminé de diseñar el PDF, copié todo a la clase original para probar un circuito entero y me da la siguiente excepción:

> Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/.Truck/CheckList.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()'

Lo raro es que ya estoy controlando el Uri de la siguiente manera:

```
//Cierro las instancias del PDF
document.Close();
docPDF.Close();

//Genero un nuevo Uri para poder abrirlo
Android.Net.Uri uri;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(pdf);
file.SetReadable(true);

//Dependiendo de la versión de Android (mayor a 7) completo el Uri
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    string strUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString();
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(strUri);
}
else
{
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
}

//Genero el Intent con el cual voy a abrir el PDF
Intent verPDF = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
verPDF.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
verPDF.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
verPDF.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
verPDF.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

if (file.Exists())
{
    //Si el archivo existe lo muestro
    StartActivity(verPDF);
}
```

Este mismo código, en la clase `Test.cs` funciona sin problemas, pero en la clase original en la que debe ir, me tira la excepción en el `StartActivity(verPDF);` y no encuentro motivo de por qué no funciona.

[EDIT]

Me olvidé de aclarar que los permisos de lectura y escritura los pido en el `OnCreate()` de la clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir del api 23 se introdujeron nuevos permisos en tiempo de ejecución por lo que hay que añadir algo de código para permitir al file provider de Android generar y visualizar ese pdf.

**Paso 1:**
Crear un archivo xml en `Resources/xml` del proyecto Android y nombralo como provider_paths.xml (o como te parezca) y agregale este código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Paso 2:**
Agrega este código al Manifest para dar acceso al archivo anterior:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

**Paso 3:**
Cambiar el código donde se lanza el Activity para abrir el pdf por el siguiente código:

```
public void OpenPDFFile(string filePath, string nameFile){
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    string extensionPath = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
    
    var externalPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/" + nameFile + extensionPath;
    File.WriteAllBytes(externalPath, bytes);
    
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(externalPath);
    file.SetReadable(true);
    
    string extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString());
    string mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    Android.Net.Uri path = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", file);
    intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    
    try{
        StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Elegir App"));
    }catch (Exception){
        Toast.MakeText(this, "No hay aplicación para abrir el PDF", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Siguiendo estos 3 pasos pude resolver mi problema. Espero que también pueda ayudar a alguien más.